# BETWEEN (inclusive) two date range

Tags: t-sql, between

I am trying to make time adjustment (due to summer time change).

I have a bottom table with datetime as data type (in Azure SQL) created.

This is **DIM** table, and this is what I have now:

```
   start_dt                  end_dt                     hour_diff
   2022-01-22 00:00:00.000   2022-03-13 01:59:59.000    -5
   2022-03-13 02:00:00.000   2022-11-06 01:59:59.000    -4
```

What I am trying to do is, if punch time is between 1/22/2022 12:00 AM --> 3/13/2022 01:59:59 AM  (**inclusive**), it will take hour_diff of -5.

So, if somebody clocks in at 3/13/2022 1:59:59 AM, it will be -5 hour_diff.

If punch time is between 3/13/2022 2:00 AM --> 11/6/2022 01:59:59 AM  (**inclusive**), it will take hour_diff of -4.

So, if somebody clocks in at 3/13/2022 2:00:00 AM, it will be -4 hour_diff.

Just FYI, bottom is SQL statement that I am using:

```
select
CONVERT(nvarchar(255), DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps), 0)   punch_start,
CONVERT(nvarchar(255), DateAdd(hour,hour_diff, ps1), 0)  punch_end
from [dbo].[Table1]
cross apply
(
    values( 
           Try_Convert(datetime, punch_start), 
           Try_Convert(datetime, punch_end) 
           )
) x (ps,ps1)
left join 
[dbo].[DIM] d on
ps between d.start_dt and d.end_dt
or
ps1 between d.start_dt and d.end_dt
```

I am trying to make sure this query works with current data in **DIM** table (using **BETWEEN**).

Comment: In SQL Server, a BETWEEN is just an easy way to type a "greater than or equal to" and "less than or equal to" e.g., `WHERE x BETWEEN a AND b` is exactly the same as `WHERE x >= a AND x <= b`. Indeed, if you look in the execution plan, that is what it converts the statement to.

Comment: @seanb So, I guess my SQL query should work fine since between is inclusive, right?

Comment: Given your upper criterion of (say) `2022-03-13 01:59:59.000`, the the BETWEEN should be OK if (and only if) it is impossible to record a time between `01:59:59.000` and `02:00:00.000` e.g., a time of `01:59:59.678` is impossible. This means knowing what data type you're using for the date/time variable and how much precision it has. Theoretically and for cleanliness, you should use >= a and < b (rather than <= b) so that b is a non-inclusive upper limit, but in practice <= 01:59:59.999999 would be fine if the date/time cannot be more precise than that.